# Acting on didSelectRowAtIndexPath during UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, uisearchdisplaycontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UIImageView and a UISearchDisplayController. When the user taps on the image, the search display controller appears. I’m filtering a list based on the search text and the table associated with the UISearchDisplayController is correctly updated. When the user taps on an row in the table, I am receiving the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. That’s what *is* working. (I used [this tutorial](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/ios-implementing-a-basic-search-uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-interface-builder/) to help me implement the UISearchDisplayController.)

However, I can’t figure out how to (a) remove the UISearchDisplayController (i.e., the search box and table) from within didSelectRowAtIndexPath and (b) how to pass information about the row that was selected to the UIScrollView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A) You should be able to dismiss the UISearchDisplay Controller with something like:

```
[searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

B) I am assuming you are launching a new view controller to display information about the row selected? If so, do something like this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNibName" bundle:nil];
MyObject *object = [allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// pass object to view controller's "object" property
viewController.object = object;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Sorry if anything is out of syntax, didn't type into xcode.

Comment: Perfect. The "A" was what I needed. I didn't need "B" because I was returning to my RootViewController. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Not a problem :) Please accept the answer if it solves the issue.